# Composite C1 Cannot Localize News Articles Using News Module

Tags: c1-cms

I'm new to Composite C1, and am just starting to research into this powerful ASP.NET based CMS.

How do I created a localized news module in Composite C1? Adding a new language in the C1 control panel allows me to localize all my pages, but strangely enough, there does not seem to be an option for me to localize the news articles (Composite.News module from Composite A/S)  themselves.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard News module is really basic. To extend it, go to the *Data* perspective in the Backend and look for the **NewsItem** datatype. You should find it under "Page Datafolders".

There you can additional properties to the News or change the data type's settings.

What you are looking for is to **enable localization** for the NewsItem datatype. Read how to do this in this short article:

[Localizing datatypes](http://docs.composite.net/Data/Customizing-Datatypes/Localizing-Data-Types#_Localizing_Datatypes_1)

The part you want is named "Localizing Existing Data Types".

After you enabled localization you can translate the News Items like normal pages.